# Conditional probability, how to find P(A)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The conditional probability Pr[B|A] is 4/5; the conditional probability P[B|not A] is 2/5, and the unconditional probability of B is 1/2. What is the probability of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the law of total probability, which implies that
$$\Pr[B] = \Pr[B \, | \, A] \Pr[A] + \Pr[B \, | \, \text{not } A] \Pr[\text{not } A].$$